# How to access the member of union in loop?

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

Trying to get the address of receiving XBee's data in the loop in API mode with escape.
Sent data can be received properly. However, in order to identify XBee, I need the address in the loop. In other words I need those address1 to 7 which is in union XbEE_FRAME. How to get the address in main loop. Following is the code. Appreciate your help.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


struct SENSOR_DATA{
   char rpm;   // worked
  //float rpm;
  //float strain;
  //unsigned long sampling_interval;
};

boolean xbee_rx(struct SENSOR_DATA *ret) {
  union LEN_FRAME{
    byte len_array[2];
    word len;
  }lenlen;
  static int len_i = -1;

  union XbEE_FRAME{
    byte buf[25]; // 30
    struct {
      byte frame_type;
      byte frame_id;
      byte address1;
      byte address2;
      byte address3;
      byte address4;
      byte address5;
      byte address6;
      byte address7;
      byte reserved1;
      byte reserved2;
      byte recieve_options;
      struct SENSOR_DATA sensor_data;
      byte checksum;
    } frame;
  } xbee;
  static int buf_i = -1;
  static bool escape = false;
  static byte sum;

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    byte b = Serial.read();

    //Serial.print(b, HEX);

     //b = Serial.read();
    if (
      b != 0x7e &&
      buf_i == -1 &&
      len_i == -1
      ) {
      continue;
    } else if (b == 0x7e){
      buf_i = 0;
      lenlen.len = 0;
      len_i = 0;
      sum = 0;
      escape = false;
      continue;
    } else if (b == 0x7d){
      //Serial.print("es: ");
      //Serial.println(b,HEX);
      escape = true;
      continue;
    }

    if (escape){
      b = b ^ 0x20;
      escape = false;
    }

    if (len_i < 2){
      lenlen.len_array[1 - len_i] = b;
      len_i++;
    } else {
      xbee.buf[buf_i++] = b;
      sum += b;
    }
    if (
      len_i == 2 &&
      buf_i >= sizeof(xbee.buf)
      ){
      len_i = -1;
      buf_i = -1;
      // frame recieved !!
      if (sum == 0xff){ // check sum!
        *ret = xbee.frame.sensor_data;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);   // 38400
  Serial.println("overover");
}

void loop() {
  //mySerial.println("work");
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 struct SENSOR_DATA data;
  if (xbee_rx(&data)){   
    //Serial.print(data.rpm);

     // if(b == 0x40 )  //&& b == 0xd5 && b == 0xaa && b == 0xac
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function xbee_rx() only returns the contents of `struct SENSOR_DATA` which doesn't include those addresses. You could instead 1) return the contents of the entire `struct {...} frame` which does contain them (making sure `loop()` 's buffer is large enough; or 2) instead of returning all of that data at all, make the `union {...} xbee` static so it persists after `xbee_rx()` exits, and return a pointer to `sensor_data`, with which loop() can access any member of it, such as `p->address1`.

Update:
The caller - rather than the called-function - allocates the memory buffer and the called-function uses that memory instead of its own, effectively passing the data to the caller. Here's your code, slightly re-written, with my initialed comments. I have not tried to run it but it does compile:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


struct SENSOR_DATA{
   char rpm;   // worked
  //float rpm;
  //float strain;
  //unsigned long sampling_interval;
};

//-jr-: Here we define what an XbEE_FRAME is and make it a data-type
// but we don't allocate any storage. This is just information to the
// compiler:
typedef union {
    byte buf[25]; // 30
    struct {
      byte frame_type;
      byte frame_id;
      byte address1;
      byte address2;
      byte address3;
      byte address4;
      byte address5;
      byte address6;
      byte address7;
      byte reserved1;
      byte reserved2;
      byte recieve_options;
      struct SENSOR_DATA sensor_data;
      byte checksum;
    } frame;
} XbEE_FRAME;

//-jr-: This function expects a pointer to memory (i.e., its address)
// allocated for data of type 'XbEE_FRAME' - the union from your
// original code. Note that we don't allocate any memory for it here;
// the caller is expected to do that, and this function will use what
// the caller allocated.
boolean xbee_rx(XbEE_FRAME *pXbF) {
  union LEN_FRAME{
    byte len_array[2];
    word len;
  }lenlen;
  static int len_i = -1;


  static int buf_i = -1;
  static bool escape = false;
  static byte sum;

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    byte b = Serial.read();

    //Serial.print(b, HEX);

     //b = Serial.read();
    if (
      b != 0x7e &&
      buf_i == -1 &&
      len_i == -1
      ) {
      continue;
    } else if (b == 0x7e){
      buf_i = 0;
      lenlen.len = 0;
      len_i = 0;
      sum = 0;
      escape = false;
      continue;
    } else if (b == 0x7d){
      //Serial.print("es: ");
      //Serial.println(b,HEX);
      escape = true;
      continue;
    }

    if (escape){
      b = b ^ 0x20;
      escape = false;
    }

    if (len_i < 2){
      lenlen.len_array[1 - len_i] = b;
      len_i++;
    } else {
       //-jr-: Note how we changed our reference from 'xbee.buf...' to
       // 'pXbF->buf...'! The '.' style addressing is used to refer to
       // memory we can name directly, as when you allocated that union
       // here. But now we  have to refer to it by the  pointer we received -
       // its address. The '->' symbol is how you address members of a
       // union or struct through a pointer:
      pXbF->buf[buf_i++] = b;
      sum += b;
    }
    if (
      len_i == 2 &&
      buf_i >= sizeof(pXbF->buf)
      ){
      len_i = -1;
      buf_i = -1;
      // frame recieved !!
      if (sum == 0xff){ // check sum!
    //-jr-: Notice that here we don't try to return any data;
    // we don't have to. Since We did everything in memory the
    // caller owns, the caller already has the data!
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);   // 38400
  Serial.println("overover");
}

void loop() {
  //mySerial.println("work");
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

   //-jr-: Define the entire XbEE_FRAME here and pass its address to
   // your function. The function will use _this_ local storage
   // (instead of its own) to buffer the data, so it will already
   // be here when your function returns:
   XbEE_FRAME data;     //-jr- Define the entire union here
   if (xbee_rx(&data)){    //-jr-  and pass its address to the function
      //-jr-: You can address a member such as address3 as:
      //      data.frame.address3
    //Serial.print(data.rpm);

     // if(b == 0x40 )  //&& b == 0xd5 && b == 0xaa && b == 0xac


  }
}
```

Update:

> How to get the SENSOR_DATA sensor_data?

Use: `data.frame.sensor_data.rpm` (lower case).

- `SENSOR_DATA` only describes the kind of contents in a struct, not any actual data in memory.
- `sensor_data` is one instance of such a struct.

To go a bit further, suppose frame{} contained more than one `SENSOR_DATA` in it, maybe named sensor_data_a, sensor_data_b, ..., etc. Now to get the data from, say, `sensor_data_a` it should be clear that you need to refer to the particular instance you're interested in.

Comment: JRobert, I am trying method No.1 that you have suggested, though still I cant get. Could you please write the code?

Comment: Ok, got the address. But now can not get the SENSOR_DATA sensor_data. How to get the SENSOR_DATA sensor_data?

Comment: I tried to get with Serial.print(data.frame.SENSOR_DATA.rpm); but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

The structures are defined within a function so the loop() won't have access to them.

Further the parameter returned from the function `xbee_rx()` is of type `SENSOR_DATA` which is a sibling in the `frame` structure to the data you want to read.